# Back button / backspace does not work with window.history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a solution for my website which includes using ajax to present the general information on the website. In doing this, I am changing the URL every time a user loads some specific content with the window.history.pushState method. However, when I press backspace or press back, the content of the old url is not loaded (however the URL is loaded).

I have tried several solutions presented on SO without any luck.

Here is an example of one of the ajax functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".priceDeckLink",function(){
    $("#hideGraphStuff").hide();
    $("#giantWrapper").show();
    $("#loadDeck").fadeIn("fast");
    var name = $(this).text();
    $.post("pages/getPriceDeckData.php",{data : name},function(data){
        var $response=$(data);
        var name = $response.filter('#titleDeck').text();
        var data = data.split("%%%%%%%");
        $("#deckInfo").html(data[0]);
        $("#textContainer").html(data[1]);
        $("#realTitleDeck").html(name);
        $("#loadDeck").hide();
        $("#hideGraphStuff").fadeIn("fast");
        loadGraph();
        window.history.pushState("Price Deck", "Price Deck", "?p=priceDeck&dN="+ name);
    });
});
```

Comment: looks like a job for a _setTimeout_ loop

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`pushState` alone will not make your page function with back/forward.  What you'd need to do is listen to `onpopstate` and load the contents yourself similar to what would happen on click.

```
var load = function (name, skipPushState) {
  $("#hideGraphStuff").hide();
  // pre-load, etc ...

  $.post("pages/getPriceDeckData.php",{data : name}, function(data){
    // on-load, etc ...

    // we don't want to push the state on popstate (e.g. 'Back'), so `skipPushState`
    // can be passed to prevent it
    if (!skipPushState) {
      // build a state for this name
      var state = {name: name, page: 'Price Deck'};
      window.history.pushState(state, "Price Deck", "?p=priceDeck&dN="+ name);
    }
  });
}

$(document).on("click", ".priceDeckLink", function() {
  var name = $(this).text();
  load(name);
});

$(window).on("popstate", function () {
  // if the state is the page you expect, pull the name and load it.
  if (history.state && "Price Deck" === history.state.page) {
    load(history.state.name, true);
  }
});
```

Note that `history.state` is a somewhat less supported part of the history API.  If you wanted to support all `pushState` browsers you'd have to have another way to pull the current state on popstate, probably by parsing the URL.

It would be trivial and probably a good idea here to cache the results of the priceCheck for the name as well and pull them from the cache on back/forward instead of making more php requests.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is helpful. You mentioned support issues. What is the current state of this as it stands today?

Comment: I can't speak with authority on this but according to [mozilla's info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), window.history made it into chrome v5 but the state property didn't appear til v18.  Other modern browsers seem to have supported state from the introduction of history.

Comment: Works only single back, also no forward button.

Comment: Solved: seems need to add check if this is back button call to `load()`, if it is then not to push state.

Comment: In my case it wasn't working because i was binding the popstate event to the `document` instead of the `window`... Replacing that made it working... Thanks

Comment: Pro tip: in the `popstate` listener function's `if` conditional, you can add `else { window.location.reload(); return; }` so that when you reach your starting page it will reload without any url params.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me. Very simple.

```
 $(window).bind("popstate", function() {
    window.location = location.href
  });
```

Comment: This still has one of the same problems as the original: works only single back, also no forward button. The OP solved the problem by adding a check to see if this is the back button call to `load()`, but this is a custom check and will change based on how you have your page setup.