# window.history.pushState not working for a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page which has a list of filters based on which I want to reload its main content. 
I am trying to do this by using `window.history.pushState` (HTML5) to keep updating the url's query string everytime the user changes the filters.

This works for the first filter and does not work when I added another filter after the first one.

Here is my code. The function FilteredByHospital() is called whenever there are changes in the checklist of hospitals.

```
var filters = new Object();
filters.Hospitals = new Array();
function FilteredByHospital(hospitalId) {
    debugger;
    var obj = { hospitalId: hospitalId };
    filters.Hospitals.push(obj);
    var isFirstFilter = window.location.href.indexOf('?') == -1;
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    if (isFirstFilter) {
        window.history.pushState(filters, "Filter_" + hospitalId, currentUrl + "?hospitalIds[0]=" + hospitalId);
    } else {
        window.history.pushState((filters, "Filter_" + hospitalId, currentUrl + "&hospitalIds[" + (filters.Hospitals.length - 1) + "]=" + hospitalId));
    }
}
```

The checklist of hospitals (Razor)

```
<div class="FilterBox">
    @foreach (var hospital in Model.Hospitals)
    {
        <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" name="HospitalId" value="@(hospital.Value)" onchange="FilteredByHospital('@(hospital.Value)')"/><span>@(hospital.Text)</span><br/>
    }
</div>
```

When I select one of the hospital checkboxes, the URL correctly changes to `http://localhost:56195/ApplicationHealthCheck/Index?hospitalIds[0]=139961407289011` and my Controller's action is hit.

When I do this again for another checkbox, the URL remains the same and the action is hit again with only the first hospital ID. Instead, the URL should change to `http://localhost:56195/ApplicationHealthCheck/Index?hospitalIds[0]=139961407289011&hospitalIds[1]=26419769705609`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra pair of brackets in the second pushState call.

Replaced

```
window.history.pushState((filters, "Filter_" + hospitalId, currentUrl + "&hospitalIds[" + (filters.Hospitals.length - 1) + "]=" + hospitalId));
```

with

```
window.history.pushState(filters, "Filter_" + hospitalId, currentUrl + "&hospitalIds[" + (filters.Hospitals.length - 1) + "]=" + hospitalId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look carefully at this line of your code:

```
window.history.pushState((filters, "Filter_" + hospitalId, currentUrl + "&hospitalIds[" + (filters.Hospitals.length - 1) + "]=" + hospitalId));
```

Did you notice the double parentheses at `pushState((`?

In this line, you are **not** calling `pushState` with three arguments. You are applying the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to your arguments, and then passing the result to `pushState`. Your code gets evaluted to

```
window.history.pushState(currentUrl + "&hospitalIds[" + (filters.Hospitals.length - 1) + "]=" + hospitalId);
```

Which is, obviously, is not right.