# window.history.pushState change url without removing last part

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following url:

```
https://example.com/page/foo
```

And I'm using pushstate like this:

```
window.history.pushState(window.location.href, null, 'product/'+data.name+'/'+data.item);
```

Now, the problem is that when it changes the url, it removes "foo" so the new url will be

```
https://example.com/page/product/product-name/123
```

and I don't want this, I want to keep the original url...and append the new stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href + 'product/' + data.name + '/' + data.item);

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer did not work for me, and I found a better alternative.
So in order to keep the "base url" and replace everything after just use:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, '/product/'+data.name+'/'+data.item);
```

That is, simple precede your path with a slash (/)