# after history pushState the back is not navigate

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history

I would like to change address url without navigation.
I do it like

```
    var url = window.location.href;
     url = url.split('#');
     var url_ = url[0] + '?task=product&url=' + selectedUrl;
  history.pushState(null, null, url_);
```

After then I enter on url in address bar and navigated to this url `url[0] + '?task=product&url=' + selectedUrl`.
But the problem comes when I navigate back, the address was changed but not page(the page is not load for changed url).

Now, How can I navigate back and page load by this url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back button / backspace does not work with window.history.pushState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335372/back-button-backspace-does-not-work-with-window-history-pushstate)

Comment: `pustState` only changes the url and stores some meta information but not the content of the page. You need to listen to the [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) event and update the content of your page accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

history.pushState only manipulates the browser history. I'm a bit confused by you're wording but you can always just

```
window.location = url;
```

To redirect to where you want to go

Comment: yeah, but when I click in browser Back button, it not load the page, only change the url

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. I don't think it works like you think it does, I would give this a read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API This may help as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate