# How do I make the back button work with hash URLs?

Tags: html, jquery

I am having trouble getting the back button to work with hash URLs. I have made a minimal example in the snippet below. There are three divs whose id's are colors. When I click a div, the background changes to that color and puts the tag `#color` in the URL. This is so that if a user wants to load the page with a certain color already on, they can use the URL with the corresponding hash tag. (Unfortunately, the snippet doesn't help with seeing the URL changes as far as I can tell.)

Now, if I click through multiple colors in sequence, I would like the back button to work as expected and show the sequence in reverse. However, with the code as written currently, only the url changes when clicking the back button, and note the actual state of the page.

I have seen other similar questions on this site (e.g., [Back button / backspace does not work with window.history.pushState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335372/back-button-backspace-does-not-work-with-window-history-pushstate)) and it seems like others have had a similar or identical problem. So it is clear I need to do something to fix this. But I have not been able to understand how to adapt any of the answers.

Based on my reading of those answers, here is what I've tried:

*Attempt 1.* Add `addEventListener("popstate", function () {location.reload(true);});` to the js file. This seems to work in Safari on my desktop. But in Chrome and in Safari iOS, only one iteration of the back button works.

*Attempt 2.* Add `addEventListener("popstate", function () {location.reload(true);});` and remove `window.history.pushState(undefined, undefined, '#'+thisID);`. The result is that the back button works as desired, but the window loads with the div at the top of the screen. I need it to be the case that clicking the div does **not** change the user's current scroll location. This is why that line with `pushState` was added in the first place. (Preferably, clicking the back button would also not change the location. This is not as crucial, but it seems doable since in attempt 1 the one successful iteration of the back button does not change the scroll location.)  What I don't understand is that there is a similar `pushState` line in the code for the `reset` function, which I *did not* remove in this attempt. The `pushState` line in the `reset` function is coded to remove the hash tag from the url entirely. It seems like there is something about that line that doesn't break the back button, unlike the `pushState` line for the `.label` function. But I don't understand what it is. (I have tried replacing the two instances of `undefined` in the `pushState` line for the `.label` function with `""` and `document.title` to match the `pushState` line for the `reset` function. But this didn't do anything, and I really have no idea what I'm doing here.)

```js
$('.label').on('click', function() {
  $('.label').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).css('background-color', thisID);
  window.history.pushState(undefined, undefined, '#' + thisID);
  window.location.hash = thisID;
});

$('#reset').on('click', function() {
  $('.label').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
});

var hash = window.location.hash.split("#");
$('#' + hash[1]).click();
```

```css
#menu {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.label,
#reset {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="font-size:300%">
  Color changing buttons
</div>

<div id="menu">
  <div class="label" id="red">
    red
  </div>
  <div class="label" id="blue">
    blue
  </div>
  <div class="label" id="green">
    green
  </div>
  <div class="label" id="yellow">
    yellow
  </div>
  <div id="reset">
    reset
  </div>
</div>
```