# beforeunload equivalent for popstate

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript allows you to ask the user before he leaves the page using the `beforeunload` event. For example, if my page contains an editor and I want to remind the user to save his data before he leaves.

But how could it be implemented if I use the History API? Obviously, I call `pushState`/`replaceState` from the app code, so I can check the editor's dirty flag and display a confirmation dialog, and if the user then clicks "Cancel", don't call `pushState`/`replaceState` and leave the user on the current page.

But the `popstate` event is fired by the browser when the user clicks the Back or Forward buttons, and as I understand, it's too late; at this point, the history entry is already removed, and even if I show a confirmation dialog, I cannot cancel user action if he clicks "Cancel". Is there any possibility to cancel `popstate`? I've tried `preventDefault` and it isn't working.

Comment: Try to overwrite the `history API`

Comment: Add the code you tried.

Comment: @mplungjan it is triggered only if browser exits your page and goes to another one. If you navigate using History API (`pushState`/`replaceState`) and user goes through history of these navigations, you won't have `beforeunload`, because your page is still loaded.

Comment: Sounds like you need to listen for popstate events https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335372/back-button-backspace-does-not-work-with-window-history-pushstate

Comment: [More here](https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+back+button+pushstate+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan `popstate` event allows to detect history navigation, but I cannot display confirmation dialog and cancel this navigation if user wants to stay on current page.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

If browser supports [Navigation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_API), you can listen for `navigate` event of `window.navigation` object and handle navigation:

```
window.navigation.addEventListener("navigate", evt => {
    if (evt.userInitiated) {
         // Optional: if you don't want to catch History API calls
        return;
    }
    if (evt.cancelable) {
        if (hasUnsavedChanges()) {
            if (!confirm(
                "Are you sure that you want to leave current page? " +
                "You might lose unsaved data."
            )) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Probably you can catch this event by classic "beforeunload" handler
    }
    if (evt.canIntercept) {
        // You also can use evt.intercept() instead of handling 
        // link clicks and "popstate" events to fetch and render
        // page contents without reloading.
        // Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigateEvent/intercept#examples
    }
});

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", evt => {
    if (hasUnsavedChanges()) {
        evt.returnValue = true;
    }
});
```

For the moment of writing this answer this API is supported by Chromium-based browsers (Google Chrome, Edge, Opera etc) and isn't supported by Firefox and Safari.

It seems there is no way to cancel history forward/backward movements on Firefox and Safari for the moment.